# Recursive woes - reducing an input string

Tags: c#, recursion, tokenize

I'm working on a portion of code that is essentially trying to reduce a list of strings down to a single string recursively.

I have an internal database built up of matching string arrays of varying length (say array lengths of 2-4).

An example input string array would be:

```
{"The", "dog", "ran", "away"}
```

And for further example, my database could be made up of string arrays in this manner:

```
(length 2) {{"The", "dog"},{"dog", "ran"}, {"ran", "away"}}
(length 3) {{"The", "dog", "ran"}.... and so on
```

So, what I am attempting to do is recursively reduce my input string array down to a single token.  So ideally it would parse something like this:

```
1) {"The", "dog", "ran", "away"}

Say that (seq1) = {"The", "dog"} and (seq2) = {"ran", "away"}

2) {  (seq1), "ran", "away"}
3) {  (seq1), (seq2)}

In my sequence database I know that, for instance, seq3 = {(seq1), (seq2)}

4) {  (seq3)  }
```

So, when it is down to a single token, I'm happy and the function would end.

Here is an outline of my current program logic:

```
public void Tokenize(Arraylist<T> string_array, int current_size)
{
  // retrieve all known sequences of length [current_size] (from global list array)
  loc_sequences_by_length = sequences_by_length[current_size-min_size]; // sequences of length 2 are stored in position 0 and so on

  // escape cases
  if (string_array.Count == 1)
  {
    // finished successfully
    return;
  }
  else if (string_array.Count < current_size)
  {
    // checking sequences of greater length than input string, bail
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    // split input string into chunks of size [current_size] and compare to local database 
    // of known sequences
    // (splitting code works fine)

    foreach (comparison)
    {
      if (match_found)
      {
        // update input string and recall function to find other matches
        string_array[found_array_position] = new_sequence;
        string_array.Removerange[found_array_position+1, new_sequence.Length-1];
        Tokenize(string_array, current_size)
      }
    }   
  }

  // ran through unsuccessfully, increment length and try again for new sequence group
  current_size++;
  if (current_size > MAX_SIZE)
    return;
  else
    Tokenize(string_array, current_size);
}
```

I thought it was straightforward enough, but have been getting some strange results.
Generally it appears to work, but upon further review of my output data I'm seeing some issues.  Mainly, it appears to work up to a certain point...and at that point my 'curr_size' counter resets to the minimum value.

So it is called with a size of 2, then 3, then 4, then resets to 2.
My assumption was that it would run up to my predetermined max size, and then bail completely.

I tried to simplify my code as much as possible, so there are probably some simple syntax errors in transcribing.  If there is any other detail that may help an eagle-eyed SO user, please let me know and I'll edit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't step 3 (`{{"The", "dog"}, {"ran", "away"}}`) already only one group?

Comment: i'll edit to better reflect what's going on

Comment: Did you mean 4) { {{"The"}, {"dog"}}, {{"ran"}, {"away"}} }?

Comment: p.s. All those underscores burn my eyes and I can feel my hands aching just thinking about reaching the _ constantly.  Please use camel casing for variable names.

Comment: I consider myself pretty smart but I am having issues wrapping my apparently simple brain around your question.

Comment: Suppose you find a match. You remove the old sequence and insert the new sequence, and then you recurse. When the recursion finishes, you keep on going through the loop, searching for more matches. Shouldn't there be a return after the recursive step?

Comment: what Eric said and perhaps an example real input that has "strange results" and the results themselves

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is why this algorithm is recursive in the first place. Posit: you have a method that can do a single "reduction" on a list. Algorithm: sit there in a loop doing nothing but calling Reduce over and over again, until such a time as the array size stops going down. And you're done. No recursion necessary.

Comment: @Eric, would you mind rephrasing your comment in the form of an answer.  I reworked it without recursion and it works much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what all the issues are, but the first thing I'd do is have your "catch-all" exit block right at the beginning of your method.

```
public void Tokenize(Arraylist<T> string_array, int current_size)
{
  if (current_size > MAX_SIZE)
    return;

  // Guts go here

  Tokenize(string_array, ++current_size);
}
```

A couple things:

1. Your tokens are not clearly separated from your input string values.  This makes it more difficult to handle, and to see what's going on.
2. It looks like you're writing pseudo-code:

   - loc_sequences_by_length is not used
   - found_array_position is not defined
   - `Arraylist` should be `ArrayList`.
   - etc.

Overall I agree with James' statement:

> It would help if you cleaned up the
>   code, to make it easier to read.

-Doug

Comment: winner because you helped me to rethink my approach...thanks for the input!

Comment: No problem - I'm glad it helped somehow! :)

Answer (score 1):

One bug is:
`string_array[found_array_position] = new_sequence;`

I don't know where this is defined, and as far as I can tell if it was defined, it is never changed.

In your if statement, when if `match_found` ever set to true?

Also, it appears you have an extra close brace here, but you may want the last block of code to be outside of the function:

```
     }
    }   
  }
```

It would help if you cleaned up the code, to make it easier to read. Once we get past the syntactic errors it will be easier to see what is going on, I think.